# Running a method of a es2016 react component using Ref or not from outside this component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component called SoccerTeam. Inside this component I have a state variable called players that is an array of objects. Each object represents a player. From outside this component, I need to add a player object to the SoccerTeam players state variable. The players state variable is only declared inside the SoccerTeam. I was thinking on creating a function inside SoccerTeam to allow me to add a player but... is this the best way to do so? how to? I read that the use of ref must be avoided but if this is unavoidable how to do this with ref? Can the use of ref be avoided? I can not pass a list to players as SoccerTeam could define the content of its state variable players at the beginning of the life-cycle of SoccerTeam.I saw an example that uses old react syntax (which is being abandoned). Is there any advantage using ES2016?

Comment: Have you read about [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)?

Comment: This is like placing the players state variable out of SoccerTeam but into the state of the component using SoccerTeam. However, since I am trying to re-use SoccerTeam without extracting the players state variable this is not a path I will like to follow.